# How to convert image to text (OCR) with Xcode 4.2?

Tags: ios, ocr

I want to extract the text data from the image by using ocr scanner. After a google
I found so much sample codes but those are not working in our xcode. I also changed the build sdk. And one of the sample code executed successfully but the service url is not in active state it seems

> "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request The language parameter is missing"

I downloaded the project by using this "https://github.com/rcarlsen/Pocket-OCR".

Please tell me how to get my solution. Also please suggest any tutorials regarding it.